# Excel Row Select

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a macro to color code some rows of a data sheet I have.

Part of this macro involves selecting a series of rows, let's say from row `nA` to row `nB`. I have tried:

```
Rows(nA:nB).select
```

which causes

```
Compile Error:
Expected: list seperator or )
```

and

```
Rows("nA:nB").select
```

which causes

```
runtime error
type mismatch
```

Any advice on how to solve this?

Comment: Try recording a macro, and doing what you want to do manually .. then look at what it wrote ;) It'll show you the exact command, you just need to tweak it for your ranges ...  ;)

Comment: is nA and nB a number or a variable? As @Ditto suggested, the recorded code is: Rows("1:4").Select so maybe there is something off in how you're setting the rows to be selected.  Also, .Select is rarely needed.  You may want to give an idea of what you want to do w/ the selected rows to get a better idea of how to go about it.  For instance: Rows("1:4").Cells.Interior.Color = 255 will color rows 1 - 4 red.  No select needed.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need

```
Rows(nA & ":" & nB).Select
```

to match exactly what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

definitely do the record macro like was suggested.

```
Range("B3:C10").Select
Selection.Copy
```

another example:

```
rowstart = 3
rowend = 10
colstart = "B"
colend = "C"

rcstart = colstart & rowstart
rcend = colend & rowend

Range(rcstart, rcend).Select
' or you can combine like below
Range(colstart & rowstart, colend & rowend).Select

Selection.Copy
```

Comment: No need to use Select at all.